# ASP.NET Gridview Editing

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I set the EditIndex property of the GridView from the RowCommand event?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to set the EditIndex property:

```
protected void gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandArgs e)
{
   gridView.EditIndex = gridView.SelectedIndex;
}
```